# Pythonic way invert matching

Tags: regex, python-2.6

I am trying achieve pythonic way to invert match. With egrep I can do it easily like this:

```
egrep -v "\.jpg|\.gif|\.png|GET \/ HTTP\/1\.*" filename.
```

How one would invert match that pattern with python 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your `filename` was a string containing multiline text, give this a try:

```
[x for x in filename.split('\n') if not re.match(r'.*(\.jpg|\.png|...).*',x)]
```

if your `filename` is already a list of text:

```
[x for x in filename if not re.match(r'.*(\.jpg|\.png|...).*',x)]
```

if it is a file, first read and do the same.